# how to test ReadDir for nfs server

Tags: testing, server, nfs, readdir

I've modified some of the nfs server functions using another server connecting between the client and the server.

I would like to test the `ReadDir` function for NFS, but whatever I try to test it, the command sent is `ReadDirPlus (ls, ls -l etc.)`

is there a specific command via terminal (bash) to request a `ReadDir` command for NFS?

Comment: I Created a Client and used clnt_call to create requests for my server

Answer (score 0):

Use NFS version 2, instead of 3.  There's no READDIRPLUS in version 2.  The client has to issue the READDIR, then do individual GETATTRs to retrieve the attributes for an ls -l.

If you're using Linux, simply issue the mount command with nfsvers=2.

Comment: that's not solving anything :|